# CoolProp script from Python to Julia

Tags: python, julia

I try to repeat the examples shown, [Cycle Calculations](http://coolprop.sourceforge.net/coolprop/python-cycles.html)

But I don't know how to translate the following line correctly,

I receive the following alert, in the developed script

```
using PyCall
Julia>pyimport("sys").executable

Julia>@pyimport CoolProp.CoolProp as CP

Julia>@pyimport CoolProp.Plots as CPP #StateContainer

Julia>T0 = 300.000; p0 = 200000.000; h0 = 112745.749; s0 = 393.035;

Julia>cycle_states = CPP.StateContainer()
15:36:55->>PyObject <CoolProp.Plots.SimpleCycles.StateContainer object at 0x00000000427A9AF0>

Julia>cycle_states['H'] = h0
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::PyObject, ::Float64, ::Char)
Closest candidates are:
  setindex!(::PyObject, ::Any, ::Union{AbstractString, Symbol}) at C:\Users\hermesr\.julia\packages\PyCall\tqyST\src\PyCall.jl:346
  setindex!(::PyObject, ::Any, ::Integer) at deprecated.jl:70
  setindex!(::PyObject, ::Any, ::Integer, ::Integer) at deprecated.jl:70
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[191]:1
```

How to achieve the following command: print (cycle states).
I have tried

```
@pycall(cycle_states)
ERROR: ArgumentError: Usage: @pycall func (args …) :: T;
get! (cycle_states)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching get! (:: PyObject)
print(cycle states)
PyObject <CoolProp.Plots.SimpleCycles.StateContainer object at 0x0000000007E70AF0>
```

Comment: Have you tried `cycle_states["H"]`? Note double quotes.

Comment: cycle_states["H"] = h0
ERROR: KeyError: key "H" not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] _setproperty!(::PyObject, ::String, ::Float64) at C:\Users\hermesr\.julia\packages\PyCall\tqyST\src\PyCall.jl:332
 [2] setindex!(::PyObject, ::Float64, ::String) at C:\Users\hermesr\.julia\packages\PyCall\tqyST\src\PyCall.jl:348
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[193]:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For builtin containers and some numpy containers or other well known types, PyCall can automatically convert them to a julia native object. However `cycle_states` is only a dict-like object in Python and is not well known so Julia and PyCall knows nothing about how to automatically handle an unknown dict-like object so it returns a `PyObject` object, which is merely a wrapper to the underlying PyObject* pointer. Fortunately PyCall provides you tools to call functions on these underlying objects and they are clearly written in the document. I'll introduce three ways to get and set value on dict-like objects.

### use get and set! functions

PyCall provides a convenient way to call the underlying `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods, which is `get` and `set!`. So you can simply set and get values from StateContainer object.

```
julia> cycle_states = CPP.StateContainer()
ArgumentError: only Dict and Mapping objects can be converted to PyDict
julia> set!(cycle_states,"H",h0)
112745.749
julia> get(cycle_states, "H")
112745.749
```

### use PyCall string macros to use your object in Python environment

The second way to do this is also intuitive, which is using the object in its native environment. PyCall provides string macros to do this. For example

```
julia> py"""
       $cycle_states["H"] = $h0
       """

julia> py"$cycle_states['H']"
       112745.749
```

You can see there are two types of string macro, the multi-line one can run arbitrary python codes in it but it will return `nothing`, so we use it to assign values, the `py""` evaluates the expression in Python's `eval` function so it cannot assign value, but it will return value to Julia environment, so we use it to get values. Also notice the dollar sign, since `cycle_states` and `h0` are variables defined in Julia environment, we have to add the dollar sign to pass the value to Python.

### directly call the `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` method

PyCall allows you to directly call methods of an object (or any functions in Python) by using `pycall` function, `@pycall` macro or directly use function call syntax.

```
julia> pycall(cycle_states.__setitem__,PyAny,"H",h0)

julia> pycall(cycle_states.__getitem__,PyAny,"H")
       112745.749
```

Here `PyAny` type means we let PyCall to infer the return type. This will bring some performance overhead since PyCall has to determine the type at runtime and Julia's compiler cannot generate optimized code. However if you are using Python to do some heavy work I would say the overhead is negligible.

The `@pycall` macro is a convenient way to call `pycall` function. It will automatically convert to a call to `pycall`. In this example I'll specify a return type.

```
julia> @pycall cycle_states.__setitem__("H",h0)::PyObject
       PyObject None
julia> @pycall cycle_states.__getitem__("H")::Int32
       112745
```

You can see that the fractional part has disappeared since `Int32` is specified.

If you don't want to specify PyAny every time, you can directly call it and PyCall will assume the PyObject is callable.

```
julia> cycle_states.__setitem__("H",h0)

julia> cycle_states.__getitem__("H")
       112745.749
```

However if you need to specify return type you must use `pycall` or `@pycall`.

For more information about PyCall, refer to the document https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl